# Visual Studio 2015 - Unable to open link to Work Item from Work Item Description field

Tags: visual-studio, tfs-workitem

### Context

If you copy a TFS Work Item, the history tab of the copy gets an entry saying "Copied from Feature 364057" with a hyperlink to "Feature 364057". Following the link opens the Work Item in Visual Studio (as expected!).

Looking behind, the HTML is as follows: `Copied from <a href="x-mvwit:workitem/364057">Feature 364057</a>.`

If you are interested, you can try yourself using this C# code to read out the changed fields of revisions of a Work Item to get the above HTML code:

```
private static void PrintRevisions(WorkItem workItem)
{
    foreach (Revision revision in workItem.Revisions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Fields of Revision {revision.Index} | TagLine = {revision.GetTagLine()}");
        PrintFields(revision.Fields);
    }
}

private static void PrintFields(FieldCollection fields)
{
    foreach (Field field in fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{field.Name} | {field.ReferenceName} = {field.Value}");
    }
}
```

---

### Problem

If I insert exactly the same HTML in the Description tab of a Work Item, I get the following message when I want to follow that link:
[image: Unsafe link]

---

**Question 1:** Does anybody know why it is possible to open that type of link from the History tab and not from the Description tab? Maybe there is a Visual Studio setting related to the message?

---

**Question 2:** Is there another way to create links to other Work Items, in the Description tab, that open the Work Item in Visual Studio (and not in the Internet Browser)?

*Please do not refer to the functionality of creating links/relationships, e.g. via the All Links tab. I explicitly want to open links to other Work Items from within the Description field.*

Answer (score -1):

@Question1: I found the following: Microsoft states that within the "New work item tracking experience" you can link a work item in the discussion tab by typing '#' (see [New work item tracking experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/new-work-item-experience?view=vsts)). I linked an item with this method and then analyzed the JSON object which I requested via REST API. I thought I will get the same link structure as with copying:`<a href="x-mvwit:workitem/364057">`
but instead I got:

```
<a href=\"https://{MyServer}/tfs/_permalink/_workitems/edit/1234?collectionId=1234&amp;projectId=1234\" data-vss-mention=\"version:1.0\">Feature 1234: _Template Feature</a>&nbsp;<br>
```

Maybe you can provide a link with the second structure (worked for me), but generally it seems that its only for the discussion tab.